# Link to an address on Here Maps?

Tags: google-maps, maps, here-api

Is it possible to link to a specific address on https://wego.here.com as you can with Google maps like this:  https://www.google.com/maps?q=221b+Baker+Street%2C+London ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same by using Places and locating your place and getting the shortened here link to it. Please see the image attached. You can also add locations to your collection and later get the links to them. [image]

Edit (from comment):

You can do it programmatically by appending your search term like this
https://wego.here.com/search/221b-Baker-Street%2C-London

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for way of generating a link without any interaction with here.com before the event, as in the Google example.

Comment: You can do it programmatically by appending your search term like this https://wego.here.com/search/221b-Baker-Street%2C-London

Comment: Thanks, have moved your programmatic solution into the answer.